# Troubleshooting in case of tracking loss

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I created an Object to Play Animation through the HelloAR Example of ARCore. Then he covered Camera with his hand and caused a tracking loss.
And if you shine the space again, the object you create will return, but the Animation will start from the beginning.

1. If space is recognized again after the tracking loss occurs, sometimes the object is returned but not returned. Is there a way of distinguishing?
2. If you recognize space again after a tracking loss occurs, why does Animation start all over again when the object returns? Are you deleting and recreating the object?

Answer (score 1):

ARCore uses a techniques called [Visual Inertial Odometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_odometry). It is a hybrid techniques which combine computer vision and sensor fusion.

So what VIO does is it combines data extracted from feature points(corners, blobs, edges, etc) with data acquired from mobile device IMU unit. It is crucial in ARCore you know the position of your device. Because you estimate every trackable position based on this information(triangulation using device pose).

Also another aspect is ARCore builds a sparse map of the environment while you move in the room. So those extracted feature points are stored in the memory based on a confidence level and used later to localize device.

At last, what happens when tracking is lost is you **can not** extract feature points due to a while wall for example. When you **can not** extract feature points you **can not** localize the device. Therefore, device does not know where it is in this Sparse map i mentioned above. Sometimes you recover because you go back to the places which are already scanned and kept in this Sparse map.

Now for your questions:

1. If you anchor your objects. Your objects will return but there can be drifts because ARCore can accumulate errors during this process especially if you move during device tracking is lost. So probably they return but they are not at the same physical position anymore because of the drifts.
2. As in animation restarting since those anchors can not be tracked they deactivated. Also since you anchor your objects they are child of the anchor so your objects are deactivated as well. That is why your animation restart.

You can test both issues using instant preview and see what happens to anchors when you lose tracking. Good luck!